# Is there a way to add an extra attribute to the Nuxt3 script files?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, rollup, nuxt3, cookiebot

We use CookieBot and want to use it in auto-mode, but we don't want CookieBot to block the Nuxt3 scripts. In order to do that we should add an attribute to the script tag.

If we add `data-cookieconsent="ignore"`  `to \<script type="module" src="/\_nuxt/entry.8c839283.js" crossorigin\>\</script\>` CookieBot should skip the script files generated by Nuxt3

https://www.cookiebot.com/